# Extract modified date from file using the XML package in R

Tags: r, xml, metadata

I´m using the XML package to extract some metadata. I found a nice solution to extract the authors name here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/microsoft-office-metadata-with-r/. 
Using the first line of the code I get this:

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <dc:title>CHR-nr</dc:title>
      <dc:subject/>
      <dc:creator>XXXXXX</dc:creator>
      <cp:keywords/>
      <dc:description/>
      <cp:lastModifiedBy>XXXXXX</cp:lastModifiedBy>
      <cp:revision>1</cp:revision>
      <cp:lastPrinted>2013-03-22T12:16:00Z</cp:lastPrinted>
      <dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2013-03-22T12:13:00Z</dcterms:created>
      <dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2013-03-22T12:24:00Z</dcterms:modified>
    </cp:coreProperties>', asText=TRUE)
```

and I want to extract the information from these lines:

```
  <dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2013-03-22T12:13:00Z</dcterms:created>
  <dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2013-03-22T12:24:00Z</dcterms:modified>
```

using the following code (I will use the last line as example):

```
ns=c('dcterms'= 'http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/')
date = xmlValue(getNodeSet(doc, '/*/dcterms:modified\ xsi:type=\"dcterms:W3CDTF\"', namespaces=ns)[[1]])
```

but I get this error:

```
XPath error : Invalid expression
/*/dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF"
                    ^
Error in xpathApply.XMLInternalDocument(doc, path, fun, ..., namespaces = namespaces,  : 
  error evaluating xpath expression /*/dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF"
>
```

Can someone help to write the correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've not properly set up your namespaces. You need to set up both `dcterms` and `xsi` and the URL for `dcterms` in your xpath namespace needs to be the same URL as the one used in the original XML document. Plus your XPATH for filtering by attribute was a bit off. Try

```
ns <- c('dcterms'= 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/', 
     'xsi'="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
xq <- '/*/dcterms:modified[@xsi:type=\"dcterms:W3CDTF\"]'
date <- xmlValue(getNodeSet(doc, xq, namespaces=ns)[[1]])
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks! :) But why do you have to change the set up for the namespaces`?  Is there any place where I can read more about it? Thanks once again

Comment: Well, your XML document uses namespaces so your xpath query has to define them as well. It's not R specific but maybe this guide might help give an overview: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx